# Assessing uncertainty calibration in regression using the CDF

Tags: regression, uncertainty, calibration

I have a labelled data set with $n$ data points $(x_i, y_i)$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and I trained a model $f: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+$ on some of the data points using Gaussian maximum likelihood estimation. The model, therefore, outputs a mean estimate $\hat\mu(x)$ and variance estimate $\hat \sigma^2(x)$.

I want to check if my uncertainties are well-calibrated, i.e. that about 50% of the test labels fall into the 50% predicted confidence interval etc.

I set $F_i = CDF_{Gaussian} \left( \frac{(y_i-\hat \mu(x_i))}{\sqrt{\hat\sigma^2(x_i)}} \right)$
and count for 20 confidence levels $\tilde p_j  = 0.05j$ the fraction:
$$\hat p_j =  \frac{\mid\lbrace y_i\mid F_i<\tilde p_j, i = 1,2,...n\rbrace \mid}{20}.$$

Perfect calibration would then imply $\hat p_j \to p_j \forall j \in \lbrace 1,2...20 \rbrace$ when the dataset size approaches infinity.

**Does this approach convince you?**

P.S.: This is heavily based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00263), but they do not employ the CDF, which I really do not understand since their $ F_t$ is $\in \mathbb R$ and not $[0,1]$ as far as I understand.

**Edit:**

My math seems to be at best confusing, thus I am trying to formulate in English what I am trying to do:
I have a machine-learning model that outputs an estimate of a target value for each input. Additionally, it outputs an uncertainty estimate for its target prediction ability for each input. I evaluate the accuracy of the target estimate using the mean squared error on a test set. Now I am thinking about ways to evaluate the uncertainty estimates on the test set.

I trained the uncertainty estimates using a Gaussian negative [log-likelihood loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GaussianNLLLoss.html) so they are variances of a predictive Gaussian distribution.
I want the uncertainty estimates to be well-calibrated: for
example, a 68% credible interval should contain the true outcome about 68% of the time. How can I evaluate if this is fulfilled on my test data?

Comment: "Convince" us of what?  It's unclear what your estimators are estimating because you haven't formulated any probability model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does it matter how the model is formulated? I just want to evaluate the resulting estimates empirically... I have given a loose definition of good calibration, and I want to know if checking for $\hat p_j \approx p_j $ implies that the uncertainties are well calibrated. Would it help to formulate the definition of good calibration in a more formal way?

Comment: You seem to be describing several completely different things: parameter estimates, calibration of probabilities, and even the mathematical formulation (which is difficult to match to either of those applications).  Very confusing.

Comment: I linked to a paper which describes a very similar setup. https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00263 
In Formula 3, they describe their definition of calibration, for example. 
You probably won't have the time to skim it, but if you do, I´d be happy to know if you find their description equally confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the reference: it gives some good hints.  But it's still unclear what you are doing because your mathematical notation just doesn't work.  (What is "$p_i$" for instance?)  It would help to have an English description of what you are doing or perhaps a small example.

Comment: Changing "$p_i$" to "$y_i$" unfortunately doesn't help -- your notation is at least as confusing and vague as before.

Comment: Thanks for catching that mistake! At least that formula should be clearer now? :) In any case, I also tried to explain what I want to do in English, which I guess is also too vague...